# MailTo URI object in .NET?

Tags: .net, uri, mailto

Given a URI (that is confirmed to be a `Uri.UriSchemeMailto`) is there an object this can be cast to that would give provide mailto properties?

Like if the `.TargetURI` was **{mailto:your@email.com?subject=I'm all done&body=Finished&cc=his@email.com&bcc=her@email.com}** is there an object that will take this as a URI and spit back MailTo properties? Like

#### Pseudo Code

```
Dim mailDetails as New MailDetailsObject(MyURI.TargetURI)

Console.WriteLine(mailDetails.To)
Console.WriteLine(mailDetails.CC)
Console.WriteLine(mailDetails.BCC)
Console.WriteLine(mailDetails.Subject)
Console.WriteLine(mailDetails.Body)
```

That results in:

```
your@email.com
his@email.com
her@email.com
I'm all done
Finished
```

Or is this something people normally just manually parse or construct out of the properties under `.TargetURI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own class for this. It's not complete and haven't tested it with all possible parts of the schema, but it appears to work well enough for most mailtos. Feel free to edit this answer with improvements.

```
Class MailToItem
    Public Property [To] As String
    Public Property Cc As String
    Public Property Subject As String
    Public Property Body As String
    Public Property Bcc As String
    Private _mailToParameters As String()
    Sub New(uri As String)
        Dim mailtoString As String() = uri.Split("?")
        Me.To = GetEmailToRecipients(mailtoString(0).Split(":")(1))
        _mailToParameters = mailtoString(1).Split("&")
        SetOtherEmailRecipients()
        SetSubject()
        SetBody()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SetOtherEmailRecipients()
        Me.Cc = GetEmailRecipients("cc")
        Me.Bcc = GetEmailRecipients("bcc")
    End Sub
    Private Function GetEmailRecipients(type As String) As String
        Dim recipients As String = Field(type)
        If recipients IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim recipientsAll() As String
            recipientsAll = recipients.Split("=")(1).Split(",")
            Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            If recipientsAll.Count > 1 Then
                For r = 0 To recipientsAll.Count - 1
                    If r < recipientsAll.GetUpperBound(0) Then
                        s.Append(recipientsAll(r) + ";")
                    Else
                        s.Append(recipientsAll(r))
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                s.Append(recipientsAll(0))
            End If
            Return s.ToString
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    End Function
    Private Function Field(type As String) As String
        Return _mailToParameters.Where(Function(f) f.StartsWith(type, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault
    End Function
    Private Function GetEmailToRecipients(toString As String) As String
        Dim recipientsAll() As String = toString.Split(",")
        Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            If recipientsAll.Count > 1 Then
                For r = 0 To recipientsAll.Count - 1
                    If r < recipientsAll.GetUpperBound(0) Then
                        s.Append(recipientsAll(r) + ";")
                    Else
                        s.Append(recipientsAll(r))
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                s.Append(recipientsAll(0))
            End If
            Return s.ToString
    End Function
    Private Sub SetSubject()
        Dim subject As String = Field("subject")
        If subject IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Subject = NormalizeText(subject.Split("=")(1))
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub SetBody()
        Dim body As String = Field("body")
        If body IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.Body = NormalizeText(body.Split("=")(1))
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Function NormalizeText(text As String) As String
        text.Replace("%20", " ")
        text.Replace("%0A%0A", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
        text.Replace("%0A", Environment.NewLine)
        text.Replace("%0D", Environment.NewLine)
        Return text
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that passing a `.TargetURI` into the constructor may cause failures as it doesn't appear to cover the full schema. For example ***mailto:john@jim.com,jim@john.com*** (two recipients) will cause `.TargetURI` to fail. In that case, you can pass in `.TargetURI.OriginalString` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a class that does that, but you could easily extract it with the [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method:

```
var mailto = "mailto:your@email.com?subject=I'm all done&body=Finished&cc=his@email.com&bcc=her@email.com";
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(mailto.Split('?')[1]);
var subject = values["subject"];
var body = values["body"];
var cc = values["cc"];
```